# Offline Payment methods did not work after setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, event-observer, payment

I did try to add Extension attributes to Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\PaymentDetailsInterface for my custom payment module.

After setup:di:compile (it took more than two hours, is this normal??) my payment method and none of the existing OfflinePayment methods did work anymore. When placing an order in checkout I got this error message:

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Fatal Error: 'Call to a member function getMethod() on null' in '...myModule\\Observer\\BeforePlaceOrderObserver.php' on line 46","trace":"Trace is not available."}]}}
```

It shows that my Observer class was not able to get a payment object anymore. The code below is from Magento\OfflinePayments\Observer\

```
      public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
    $instructionMethods = [
        Banktransfer::PAYMENT_METHOD_BANKTRANSFER_CODE,
        Cashondelivery::PAYMENT_METHOD_CASHONDELIVERY_CODE
    ];  
if (in_array($payment->getMethod(), $instructionMethods)) {...
```

Even after rolling back my code (and compiling again) the system's behaviour is still the same. 
Additional information: 
Because I am working on a bitnami stack I do not work on the latest m2 version. Before compiling I did the trick found in [that ticket](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2404) to prevent from the related compiling error. As the author said there are several more errors but the compiling did finish.

Any ideas?

**Update:**
The raising event is "sales_order_place_after"
As far as I can see the getPayment()-method returns a null value. But I have no idea why.

Comment: Did you already flush your cache? Does it work in dev mode?

Comment: The application runs in dev mode. Yes, I have flushed the cache

Comment: Can you post the code related to that error?

Comment: It is in the posting. The error occurs on $payment->getMethod() as you can see in the error message

Comment: It is the same code snippet that is used in my module and the error occurs in both modules

Comment: I'm quite new to Magento2, but as far as I can see the problem comes from the method calling the observer. What is the raising event?

Comment: I have updated the original posting

Comment: Did you remove any payment method you were using before? P.S: Did you flush the cache by command line or by admin?

Comment: No. It is the same setup as used before the compile. Cache was flushed by admin interface

Comment: It sounds weird, but try by flushing from command line. Sometimes I ad strange issues from admin interface.

Comment: Cache flushed by command line, server restarted. But the result is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the error was my fault. Someone changed the event type in events.xml so there was no payment object reachable in this event context. The correct event is

> sales_order_payment_save_before

and it is used in the OfflinePaymentMethods, too. The usage of

> sales_order_place_after

was wrong here. Sorry for the confusion and thanks to RiccardoT for your input!